# uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression - array

Tags: jquery

I am trying this code, however i get the error above:

```
  <input id="content" class="content" name="item[content]" type="text" />

var name = $('input[item[content]]');
alert(name);
```

Basically what i want is get the content of the input. What is the correct syntax ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the attribute selector, which has the follwing format: `[attribute_name="value"]` to select the desired element. Then, use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get the value of it:

```
var name = $('input[name="item[content]"]').val();
```

Comment: yo dawg we heard you liked input